# Meteor: make layout.html WaitOn a subscription?

Tags: meteor, handlebars.js, iron-router

I'm trying to make a chat (Template.chatlist) feature that sticks to the bottom of the page (similar to the chat function on Facebook, where the chat box is persistent while the page in the background changes as the user browses to other parts of the site). So I put the chat box in a handlebars template on the layout page (so it's not rendering from the {{>yield}} template). The problem is, it's not waiting on the subscriptions before it loads (there is no route to the layout.html, so I couldn't set a waitOn on it in the router), so it's not able to pull information from my users collection.

I need to know, how can I make the layout.html page wait to load after the subscriptions are properly finished? Of course, I can put the chat template inside every page's yield template to have it wait properly, but is there a way where I don't have to do it this way?

```
<main class="main container" id="central">
  {{> yield}}
  {{> chatlist}}
</main>
```

This is sort of what the layout.html looks like right now. The chatlist template is not waiting on any data subscriptions because it's not in the yield section (and thus not controlled by the router)

I also did `Template.chatlist.helpers` and registered the user data into a helper, but for some reason when I tested it by console logging `Users.count` the console returns with zero.

Answer (score 2):

Use a region:

```
<template name="layout">
  <aside>
    {{> yield region='aside'}}
  </aside>

  <div>
    {{> yield}}
  </div>

  <footer>
    {{> yield region='footer'}}
  </footer>
</template>

Router.map(function () {
  this.route('home', {
    path: '/',
    template: 'myHomeTemplate',
    layoutTemplate: 'layout',
    yieldTemplates: {
      'myAsideTemplate': {to: 'aside'},
      'myFooter': {to: 'footer'}
    },
    waitOn: function() {
      // ...
    }
  });
});
```

See the [Iron Router docs](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/blob/devel/DOCS.md#using-a-layout-with-yields).